# Method overriding:Passing derived class object when method accepts base class object

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I have above piece of code. As shown below I want to pass derived class as argument to process method.

Please suggest any alternatives.

```
class Fruit{
}
class Apple extends Fruit{
}

public interface Juice{
public void process(Fruit fruit);
}

Class abstract AbstractFruitManager implements Juice{
}

class FruitManager extends AbstractFruitManager{
public void process(Apple apple){ //gives compilation error...
}
}
```

Comment: Just use `Fruit` there. You can still pass an `Apple`.

Answer (score 1):

do it this way

```
interface Juice {  
    void process(Fruit fruit);
}
```

and use *@Override*

```
class AbstractFruitManager implements Juice{ 
    @Override   
    public void process(Fruit fruit){
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override process method as

```
public void process(Apple apple)
```

as you do in your FruitManager class, because it would not be a Juice anymore. Each Juice instance must accept any Fruit in its process method as it was promised in Juice interface.

You have basically three options:

- rename your process method
- implement your process method for all Fruits and throw an exception for Strawberries etc.
- do not implement Juice at all